# efficient way to extract values from a field

Tags: php, mysql

One of my plugin is storing data in form of

```
a:2:{i:0;s:20:\"HELM Operational (O)\";i:1;s:19:\"HELM Management (M)\";}
```

In database . I want to get the values such as "HELM Operational,HELM Management" in php . How can i extract the values and get it into a variable in the desired form . I know we can use Explode to explode after `"` but there is dynamic non wanted values in between such as `i:1,s:19` etc which will be different every time . Is this possible using php to get the desired outcome ?

Comment: isn't this a serialized array, just try to unserialize it

Comment: This is a serialize data use PHP `unserialize()` function

Comment: Not working . I tried it

Comment: Those escaped quotes (`\"`) are the problem: looks as though somebody double escaped it when they stored it in the database

Comment: @Mark Thank you for your reply .But i can't really do anything for that, its the plugin which is doing so . Is there a way from regex , php, mysql anything to get the values i want

Answer (score 0):

If you can't fix the malformed data at source:

```
$data = 'a:2:{i:0;s:20:\"HELM Operational (O)\";i:1;s:19:\"HELM Management (M)\";}';
$data = unserialize(str_replace('\"', '"', $data));
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer . But it gives the following error `Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 6 byte`

Comment: The code I posted [works with the string you showed](http://ideone.com/CcAPJv) ... perhaps the string that you posted isn't what you're actually trying to unserialize

Comment: when i echo the value directly it was this `a:2:{i:0;s:20:"HELM Operational (O)";i:1;s:19:"HELM Management (M)";}` which was different when it was showing then in json . I tried to use simple unserialize on this `a:2:{i:0;s:20:"HELM Operational (O)";i:1;s:19:"HELM Management (M)";}` but didnt worked .

Comment: If the data doesn't have the `\"` as you've just posted in the comment here, then a simple unserialize [will work](http://ideone.com/4gUVyt)

Comment: i used simple one . But its giving error and my full code is `if(mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
            while($post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
             $tim=$post['value'];
             
             $data = unserialize($post['value']); }`

Comment: Do a var_dump() of your `$post['value']` so we can see exactly what you've got.... don't try to json encode it or anything

Comment: in var dump i get values but also error `b>array</b> <i>(size=2)</i>
  0 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'HELM Operational (O)'</font> <i>(length=20)</i>
  1 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'HELM Management (M)'</font> <i>(length=19)</i>`

Comment: No wonder you can't unserialize.... if that's what's stored in your database, then you really do need to sort out this problem at source

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71595/discussion-between-user1001176-and-mark-baker).

Comment: but that is not the data . The data stored is `a:2:{i:0;s:20:"HELM Operational (O)";i:1;s:19:"HELM Management (M)";}` . I have checked it myself

Comment: If that is the data you have stored, and are retrieving from the database, then a straight unserialize() will convert that serialized string to an array with two elements, the first being a string value of `HELM Operational (O)` the second being a string value of `HELM Management (M)`.... your problem has nothing to do with unserializing at all, but with whatever you're subsequently doing